# const in classes dont work with visibility definition

Tags: php, class

In PHP docs there is an example that uses **public const**
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#example-196

```
class MyClass
{
    public const MY_PUBLIC = 'public';
}
```

But it gives me this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php-testing/const.php on line 5"

This example works without "public". Like this

```
class MyClass
{
    const MY_PUBLIC = 'public';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifiers for constants have been added only in PHP 7.1, be sure to use the right version.

[Class Const Visibility](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_const_visibility)